# How do I add newly created mount point to fstab?

Tags: fstab

I just mounted sda2 to /mnt. How can I force a refresh of fstab so it can pickup the changes and insert a new line for sda2-/mnt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually edit the file `fstab`. To find out what to put in there, issue the `mount` command and look at its output.

Comment: ok thanks. hard to believe Linux does not do this own its own. Side note - my sda1 in fstab has the UUID listed. If I run blkid I have a UUID for sda2 as well but when I run mount the only output is "/dev/sda2 /mnt ext3 rw 0 0" - will this do it or do I need to use the UUID as well in fstab?

Comment: It is always preferable to use the filesystem's UUID in /etc/fstab because device filenames like /dev/sda2 might change if you repartition the disk, add or remove a disk.

Answer (score 6):

Linux definitely does provide the tools to do this automatically. Rather than using `mount`, you should be using `findmnt`.

```
man mount 2>/dev/null | 
grep -m1 -B1 findmnt

              For  more robust and customizable output use
              findmnt(8),  especially  in  your   scripts.

printf '%s%s 0 0\n' '/dev/disk/by-uuid/' \
    "$(findmnt -n -o UUID,TARGET,FSTYPE,OPTIONS /mnt)" |
sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

P.S. You'll want to have a look at `man fstab` for information about the `0 0` bit on the end there. They're related to `freq` and `pass` respectively. Whether or not their values above will suit you I cannot say. I can say that those are also output options available with `findmnt` - but asking it to report on them would make no sense for a disk that isn't already in `/etc/fstab`. You might also want to reconsider `/mnt` as the permanent mount point for your new `/etc/fstab` entry.

Comment: Ok I'll run some test on this. Thanks for the tip!